# How to show s with caron in RTF file [PHP]?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have template rtf text, that I open in PHP and replace some strings with some other.
I have latin2 database where I get some text that needs to be replaced in file. Result from database contains latin2 characters (s with caron (š), c with caron (č), z with caron (ž)).
When I print the result from database in web browser, it prints fine (it shows š č and ž), but when I save it in rtf file, I get copyright sign instead of s caron.
What am I doing wrong?
I tried to convert string from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-2 and vice-versa, but it doesn't work anyway.

Let's say I have string Ajdovščina.
Converting from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-2//TRANSLIT with iconv shows only Ajdov.
Converting from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-2//IGNORE with iconv shows Ajdovina.
Converting from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-2 with iconv shows the same as translit - Ajdov.

What do I need to check and fix to save it properly in file?
I'm saving it with file_put_contents.

Comment: Try htmlspecialchars and check its documentation

Comment: I should solve my problem with htmlspecialchars? Isn't this for websites?

Comment: You can use same in your website

Comment: Doesn't work. Anything else I should do?